# Removing outlying islands from US map in shapefile with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, r-sf

I downloaded level-0 US map (National border) in R(sf) format from https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html. I plotted US border (level 0) as follows:

```
library(tidyverse) 

us0 <- readRDS("<file.path>\\gadm36_USA_0_sf.rds")

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = us0, size = 1, color = "steelblue", fill = NA)
```

Resultant image shown below
[image]

I would like to remove outlying islands A and B, and move Alaska from C to C'.

I tried but failed to extract longitude and latitude data from `us0`. I searched online but did not find adequate answers on how to do this in R. I would like to know how longitude and latitude data could be extracted from `us0` with R so that I can freely delete A and B and remove C. Thank you.

Comment: "B" are not "outlying islands" in the true sense, they are the continuation of the island chain from Alaska, only on the other side of the -180 longitude line.  If you want to keep Alaska in your map then you should keep them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `raster` package and the `geom()` function you can extract the raw coordinates from the RDS object, as well as which island/state the coordinate is part of and whether it is solid or a hole. 
In your case:

```
geom(us0)
```

Then it's just a matter of finding out which vertices belong to which islands. A quick way of deleting *B* would be to delete everything with a positive x coordinate. You'll need to find out which objects correspond to Alaska if you're to move and scale it. The top of Hawaii is (i.i.r.c) lower down than the bottom of the Florida Keys so you can also get away with removing everything with a latitude less than 23.

Also, I suspect many Hawaiians would object to Hawaii being referred to as an outlying island....

Comment: I tried `geom(us0)` but was returned: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘geom’ for signature ‘"sf"’

Comment: `geom` only works for `sp` objects, not `sf`. As a hack you could try `geomcoords = geom(as(us0,"Spatial"))`.